# is the following legal in java: if (new Point(10, 20).equals(new Point(10, 20)))

Tags: java, parameters

```
if (new Point(10, 20).equals(new Point(10, 20)))
    System.out.println("The points are equivalent");
else 
    System.out.println("The points are not equivalent");
```

Would the above section of code output "The points are equivalent"

Comment: What is the implementation of `Point#equals(Object)`? What is the rest of the implementation of `Point`?

Comment: You could have answered your question yourself by trying it out. That would have been much quicker than asking it on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [java.awt.Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html), then yes it will output the two points are equal.

Read about [.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method for the Point class.

If you are not using the [java.awt.Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) class and the class you are using does not override and check the x and y with a .equals method then it will not be equal since they are two separate instances.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  It says on the java docs: 'Two instances of Point2D are equal if the values of their x and y member fields, representing their position in the coordinate space, are the same.'  This answers the question and it provides a link to the java docs about it.

Comment: What assumptions? I haven't made any assumptions about this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Could comment instead of downvoting, but true.

Comment: You need to state that you assume that OP uses `java.awt.Point` upfront.

Comment: @PM77-1 I edited it.  Thank you. From now on when using the java docs I will be sure to say that I assume they are using the class from the docs.

Comment: His link points to java.awt.Point.  Is that not good enough?

Comment: It's not good enough because it states as a fact that that's the class being discussed while the OP hasn't clearly stated that it is. Future visitors may get mislead.